# GLTF model rendering incorrectly when aframe-effects added to scene

Tags: three.js, aframe, post-processing, gltf

This is my first question about Aframe so please let me know if you need additional info.

I have tried adding this gltf model to my project
https://poly.google.com/view/1O6BWfUB6ta

I am having issues with how my gltf models are rendering when I add the aframe effects into my scene. 
[image]

When I remove the effects the model renders perfect.

[image]

You can see a demo of my project here
http://www.applaudlabs.com/belvedere/

I saw an example here that is working with gltf models and the effects so I know it should work.
https://curious-electric.com/w/experiments/aframe/campfirevr/

And I also checked th model in the gltf view with no issues
https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Please see my code below

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
 <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
  
   <!-- Bootstrap JS Dependencies -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <!-- plugins -->
  <!-- ocean -->
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.2.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- post processing effects -->
  <script src="aframe-effects.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="vr_bg">
   <div class="overlay_container">
    <a class="logo_link" href=""><img class="logo_svg" src="logo.svg" alt="Continuous Ventures"></a>
   </div>
 
   <!-- scene working without effects -->
   <a-scene> 
   
   <!-- scene not working with effects 
   <a-scene effects="bloom, godrays, fxaa"
   godrays="src:#moon; threshold: 0.0 0.0; intensity: 0.6"
   bloom="strength:0.6; radius: 0.066;"
   fxaa class="fullscreen" 
   fog="type: linear; far:1000; color: #ffc595; density:0.0025">
   -->
     
    <a-assets>
     <!-- ocean-->
     <img id="water-normal" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/textures/waternormals.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="true"/>
     <!-- sky -->
     <img id="sky" src="sky.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="true"/>
     <img id="sky_reflection" src="water_reflection_sky.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="true"/>
     <!-- Lighthouse-->
     <a-asset-item id="lighthouse" src="lighthouse/Lighthouse.gltf"></a-asset-item>
     <!-- animation-->
     <a-mixin id="fogtransition" dur="8000" easing="ease-in" direction="forward" repeat="0"></a-mixin>
     <a-mixin id="cameratransition" dur="36000" easing="ease-out" direction="forward" repeat="0"></a-mixin>
     <a-mixin id="suntransition" dur="18000" direction="forward" repeat="0"></a-mixin>
    </a-assets>
    
    <!-- fog -->
    <a-animation attribute="fog.color"
     from="#000"
     to="#ec5151"
     mixin="fogtransition">
    </a-animation>
    <a-animation attribute="fog.far"
     from="10"
     to="20000"
     mixin="fogtransition">
    </a-animation>
   
    <!-- camera-->
    <a-entity id="camera" position="0 0.81 0" rotation="2.9220847551671985 90.98569786677473 0">
     <a-camera>
     </a-camera>
    </a-entity> 
    
    <!-- ocean -->
    <a-ocean material="metalness:1; normalMap:#water-normal; normalTextureRepeat:10 10; 
    normalScale:1 1;"
    width="400" depth="400" 
    density="20" speed="0.125" 
    color="#333" opacity="1" 
    position="0 -0.4 0"
    amplitude= .25"
    amplitudeVariance= "1" wobble-normal="">
     
     <a-animation attribute="material.normalTextureOffset" 
      from="0 0" 
      to="100 100" 
      easing="linear"
      dur="10000"
      fill="both"
      repeat="indefinite">
     </a-animation>
     
    </a-ocean> 
    
    
   
    <!-- Lighthouse --> 
    <a-entity id="Lighthouse" gltf-model="#lighthouse" position="-72.005 0 -25.964" scale="2 2 2">
    </a-entity>
    
    <!-- light beam cylinder -->
    <a-entity id="LIGHTBEAM" position="-72.005 -9.036 -25.964">
     <a-cylinder material="fog:false; color:#fff; opacity:0.5; flatShading:true; emissive:#fff; emissiveIntensity:5"  
      rotation="-90 0 0" 
      height="30" 
      position="0 36 0"radius="10.5" 
      material="" 
      geometry="height:900; 
      radius:1.5">
     </a-cylinder>
     <a-animation attribute="rotation" 
      from="0  0 0" 
      to="0 360 0" 
      easing="linear"
      dur="10000"
      fill="forwards"
      repeat="indefinite">
     </a-animation>
    </a-entity>
    
   
    <!-- sky -->
    <a-sky src="#sky" material="" geometry="" scale="300 300 300" radius="5" position="" rotation="0 185 0" visible="">
    </a-sky>
    
   
    <!-- SKY AND AMBIENT-LIKE LIGHT -->
    <a-entity light="type: hemisphere; color: #0E192B; groundColor: #1D0A57; intensity: 1"></a-entity>
   
    <a-entity light="type: directional; color: #EEE; intensity: 0.5" position="-1 1 0">
     <a-entity position="100.0 100.0 -100.0" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 10.0;" material="shader: flat; color: #fff;" id="moon" rotation="" scale="" visible="">
      <a-animation attribute="position"
        from="-1046.095 -40.092 -14.131"
        to="-1046.095 150.092 -14.131"
        mixin="suntransition">
      </a-animation>
      <a-animation attribute="intensity"
        from="0"
        to="1"
        mixin="suntransition">
      </a-animation>
      <a-animation attribute="color"
        from="#ec5151" 
        to="#e2705a" 
        mixin="suntransition">
      </a-animation>
     </a-entity>
    </a-entity>

   </a-scene>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Eoin

Comment: In both of your screenshots the model is rendering. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Hey Diego, thank you so much for getting back to me. The problem is the wavy lines on the steps and if you look at the window box seems to be having an issue determining which face should be displayed if that makes sense? I may be misidentifying an issue and I apologise if that's the case.

Comment: That’s probably caused by the postprocessing effects you’re applying and how they combine. It’s not related to the model.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Good to know. I'll monkey around with the settings and see if I can calm it down. I appreciate you getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my gltf scene - solve by setting your camera near & far frustum culling values.

`<a-camera near="1" far="100"></a-camera>`